# Create pie chart with variables from report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart with calculated variables from report jrxml file. I created bar char successfully with

**series expression**: *"1.Budget Sales*
**Category expression**: *new Integer(1)*
**Value expression**: *`$V{ptd_budget_sales}`*

like that I added four series for four bars.

I need to use same way to create pie char. but in pie chart have only one section value

```
key expression
value expression
label expression
```

cant give more than one.

I usually pass pie char value from *Java* data source but now i need to take values from calculated variables only. I Google but found similar questions without answer. Please anybody help me or any link...

I read somewhere that can create from csv file too. In that case how to create a csv file from report? I know to create from *Java* but not from report ...any suggestion is appreciated..

Comment: Are you calculating the variables within the report?  Or from outside the report in Java?

Comment: I am calculating variables inside report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Thomas Zimmer thanks for reply

I done this with if condition of Value expression

(java.lang.Integer.parseInt($F{Value}.toString()) == 1 ? new java.lang.Double($V{ptd_labour_othPur_cost}.doubleValue()) : 
(java.lang.Integer.parseInt($F{Value}.toString()) == 2 ? $V{ctc_labour_othPur_cost} : 
(java.lang.Integer.parseInt($F{Value}.toString()) == 3 ? new java.lang.Double($V{ptd_ico_subcon_cost}.doubleValue()) : 
(java.lang.Integer.parseInt($F{Value}.toString()) == 4 ? $V{ctc_ico_subcon_cost} : 
(java.lang.Integer.parseInt($F{Value}.toString()) == 5 ? $V{predict_profit} : 
new java.lang.Double(6) ) ) ) ) )

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a csv. pls. post your report, that will make a concrete answer easier.
Do you use different variables to show in the chart?
At which time are the variables ready? 
Maybe using a group in the report or setting the increment type could be a clue...